# Изменение имени пакета Android приложения (Flutter) в соответствии с названием сайта

Tags: android, flutter, package, rename

В качестве имени пакета для еще неопубликованного андроид-приложения (Flutter) было выбрано уникальное имя, но оно не имеет отношения к  имени сайта, содержащего информацию о приложении.
Есть ли какой то смысл заморачиваться с переименованием пакета, чтобы как рекомендует Гугл имя было: com.sitename.appname.
То есть может быть  Гугл осуществляет автоматическую привязку в своей поисковой системе сайта и приложения по его названию пакета или эти вещи никак не связаны между собой и имя пакета- это просто уникальный идентификатор приложения в googleplay и на мобильном устройстве пользователя?

Comment: идентификатор приложения вообще никак не связан с сайтами. Они просто совершенно случайно выглядят похоже. Никакой привязки гугл не осуществляет. А где кстати рекомендуется именно com.sitename.appname?

Comment: спасибо за ответ, в принципе я тоже так думал, но полной уверенности в этом не было